# How can we Spanning a Channel Entry Across Multiple Pages using pagination.?

Tags: pagination

ExpressionEngine includes a feature that allows  to automatically split a single channel entry/article across multiple pages. how can i do this?

**UPDATE**

hi  this is my code  : here am using one field for pull out the entire news that is 
{news text} ;i hav only one field .. for entire news... is this correct or required another  fields..summery  ,body ,extended  etc

```
{exp:channel:entries category_group="32" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1" paginate_type="field" paginate="bottom" }

    <div class="anw-readmorenewstitle">{title}</div>
    <div class="anw-readmorenewswriter"> {news_writer}</div>

    <div class="anw-readmorenewsimage"><img class="addthis_shareable" src="{news_image_1:anw-readsection}"  addthis:title="{title}" border="0"></div>

    <div class="anw-readmorenewsimagecaption">{news_image_1_caption}</div>

    <div class="anw-readmorenewstext">{news_text}

    {multi_field="page1|page2| page3"}
    <div>
    Last updated on {edit_date format='%M %d, %Y'} at
    {edit_date format='%h:%i %A'}<br />
    </div>

    {paginate}
    <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages for this article
    {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}


    {comments}
    </div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is one of my detailed news page .. a long articles.. I want to split this content into different pages..

"pagination_base" this tag is required or not ?

Comment: Where did you see mention of this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the documentation for setting up pagination? Do you have any code you can post of where you are at with things? It would be helpful for others to assist you if you posted your code along with what you are trying to accomplish.

You can see examples of using pagination here:

[Pagination Spanning](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/pagination_spanning.html)

Answer (score 0):

To span one entry across multiple pages EE natively requires the use of multiple content fields:

[EE Docs for multiple content fields](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/pagination_spanning.html#multi-field)

You determine how the content splits into chunks by how you split up the content into the multiple fields.

In your code you have:

```
{multi_field="page1|page2| page3"}
```

Which assumes you have fields with the names of page1, page2 and page3 in the fieldset assigned to the channel.